# extracting text blocks from input file with awk or sed and save each block in a separate output file

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to use "awk" to extract text blocks (first field/column only, but multiple lines, the number of lines vary between blocks) based on separators (# and --. These columns represent sequence IDs.

Using "awk" I am able to separate the blocks and print the first column, but I can not redirect these text blocks to separate output files.

Code:

```
awk '/#/,/--/{print $1}' OTU_test.txt
```

Ideally, I would like to save each file (text block excluding the separators) based on some text found in the first line of each block (e.g. MEMB.nem.6; MEMB.nem. is content, but the number changes)

Example of input file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vnj5.png)

```
#OTU_MEMB.nem.6
EF494252.1.2070 6750.0 D_0__Eukaryota;D_1__Opisthokonta;D_2__Nucletmycea;D_3__Fungi;D_7__Dothideomycetes;D_8__Capnodiales;D_9__uncultured fungus 1.000
FJ235519.1.1436 5957.0 D_0__Eukaryota;D_1__Opisthokonta;D_2__Nucletmycea;D_3__Fungi;D_7__Dothideomycetes;D_8__Capnodiales;D_9__uncultured fungus 1.000
New.ReferenceOTU9219 5418.0 D_0__Eukaryota;D_1__Opisthokonta;D_2__Nucletmycea;D_3__Fungi 1.000 
GQ120120.1.1635 471.0 D_0__Eukaryota;D_1__Opisthokonta;D_2__Nucletmycea;D_3__Fungi;D_7__Dothideomycetes;D_8__Capnodiales;D_9__uncultured fungus 0.990
--
#OTU_MEMB.nem.163
New.CleanUp.ReferenceOTU59580 12355.0 D_0__Eukaryota;D_1__Opisthokonta;D_2__Holozoa;D_3__Metazoa (Animalia);D_7__Chromadorea;D_8__Monhysterida 0.700
New.ReferenceOTU11809 1312.0 D_0__Eukaryota;D_1__Opisthokonta;D_2__Holozoa;D_3__Metazoa (Animalia);D_7__Chromadorea;D_8__Monhysterida 0.770
--
#OTU_MEMB.nem.35
New.CleanUp.ReferenceOTU120578 12116.0 D_0__Eukaryota;D_1__Opisthokonta;D_2__Holozoa;D_3__Metazoa (Animalia);D_7__Chromadorea;D_8__Desmoscolecida;D_9__Desmoscolex sp. DeCoSp2 0.780
```

Expected output files (first column only, no separators).

`MEMB.nem.6.txt`

```
EF494252.1.2070 
FJ235519.1.1436 
New.ReferenceOTU9219 
GQ120120.1.1635
```

`MEMB.nem.163.txt`

```
New.CleanUp.ReferenceOTU59580
New.ReferenceOTU11809
```

`MEMB.nem.35.txt`

```
New.CleanUp.ReferenceOTU120578
```

I have searched a lot, but so far I have been unsuccessful. I would be very happy if someone can advice me.

Thanks,

Tiago

Comment: You're experiencing one of the reasons why you should never use range expressions (`/start/,/end`) - the tiniest requirements change requires a complete rewrite or duplicate conditions. Always use a flag instead (`/start/{f=1} f; /end/{f=0}`).

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '
sub(/^#OTU_/,"") {
    close(out)
    out = $0 ".txt"
    next
}
!/^--/ {
    print $1 > out
}
' file
```

Comment: Dear Ed, thanks for your answer. I tested the script and works great! The only thing is that the script adds the "MEMB.nem.6" in the output file; ideally I would like to have first column of each block but skipping the first line (no MEMB.nem.6 in the txt, only : EF494252.1.2070 
FJ235519.1.1436 
New.ReferenceOTU9219 
GQ120120.1.1635). I am now looking into this to see if I can figure it out. I believe I should play with the section "print $1 > out". Once again, thanks a lot for your help! It was amazing! Sincerely, Tiago

Comment: Just add a line that just says `next` after the line that says `out = $0 ".txt"`. I updated the script to add that.

Comment: Hi Ed, Fantastic! just tried and worked beautifully! Again, thanks a lot for your help !